# Mysql - data manipulation - update part of value

Tags: mysql

Mysql table contain column with `date` type. There are some rows with different dates (i.e. `2008-01-20`,  `2007-02-25`)

Is there some mysql queue syntax to update only values with `2007` year to `2010` without changing month and day.

And the same question about changing only month. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
UPDATE table
   SET date_column = concat(concat(concat('2010-',MONTH(date_column)),'-'),DAY(date_column))
 WHERE YEAR(date_column)=2007
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET datecolumn = DATE_ADD(datecolumn, INTERVAL 3 year)
WHERE YEAR(datecolumn) = 2007
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
update table set column = value where YEAR(datecolumn) in(2007, 2008, 2009, 2010)
```